# How does dplyr::mutate apply changes to multiple columns within the same mutate command?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, mutate

I have noticed when working with the mutate function that the result is different when I change multiple columns within the same mutate command compared to multiple mutate commands connected by pipes.
I assumed that within a mutate command, the changes are made one after the other and the result of previous changes within the same mutate command is applied. Is this assumption wrong?

In the following example, a sumscore is to be calculated from the columns x_1, x_2 and x_3.
The column y_1 is only intended to illustrate that there are other columns in the actual problem, which is why the commands cannot simply be applied to all columns.

Example Data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x_1 = c(2, 3,4,5,4,3),
  x_2 = c(NA,4,2,3,4,1),
  x_3 = c(NA,2,3,1,3,NA),
  y_1 = c(3, 4,5,2,3,2)
)
```

When calculating the score, ONE missing can be replaced by the row mean of the other items. If more than one item is missing, the score cannot be calculated.
To implement this:
(1) The variable x_miscount is created, in which the number of missings is counted.
(2) The row mean (x_rowmean) over the x columns is calculated.
(3) Missings in every x column are replaced with the rowmean if the missing count is exactly 1.
(4) The sumscore is calculated.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x_miscount = rowSums(is.na(select(., x_1:x_3))),
         x_rowmean = rowMeans(select(., x_1:x_3), na.rm = T),
         across(.cols = c(x_1:x_3),
                .fns = ~if_else(is.na(.) & 
                                  x_miscount == 1,
                                x_rowmean, 
                                .)),
         x_score = rowSums(select(., x_1:x_3)))
```

However you can see in row 6 of the result, that the x_score column is NA, although the missing in column x_3 was correctly replaced by the rowmean.

If the score is calculated in a new mutate command everything works as intended:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x_miscount = rowSums(is.na(select(., x_1:x_3))),
         x_rowmean = rowMeans(select(., x_1:x_3), na.rm = T),
         across(.cols = c(x_1:x_3),
                .fns = ~if_else(is.na(.) & 
                                  x_miscount == 1,
                                x_rowmean, 
                                .))) %>% 
  mutate(x_score = rowSums(select(., x_1:x_3)))
```

Does anybody know how dplyr::mutate makes changes if multiple columns should be changed within the same command? I don't get the difference between the two examples and I'm confused by the different results.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your example. I got the same result in both cases.

Comment: `across` applies a function to the first selected column, then the next etc. In contrast, to aggregate multiple columns row-by-row, there's: `c_across` in combination with `rowwise`: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/c_across.html

Comment: @Ric thanks for the comment. I have tried to check the problem in a new project to rule out other sources of error. However, I still get different results. 

The difference is quite small. The only difference should be in line 6 of the x_score variable. Everything else should be the same.

Comment: @I_O Thank you for pointing out c_across. In the concrete example, I wanted to avoid using rowwise() because of its performance problems (my actual project contains many more rows). As far as I can tell, the replacement of the missings is done correctly and is faster than with rowwise(). 

However, I will check if my problem (calculating the score after replacing the missings) is specifically related to the use of across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is the use of `select(., x_1:x_3)`, not a problem with the way mutate updates. The `(.)` placeholder refers to the object on the left-hand side of the `%>%` expression, which in this case is df *before the application of* `mutate`.

You'll notice that this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    x_miscount = rowSums(is.na(select(., x_1:x_3))),
    x_rowmean = rowMeans(select(., x_1:x_3), na.rm = T),
    across(
      .cols = c(x_1:x_3),
      .fns = ~ if_else(is.na(.) & x_miscount == 1, x_rowmean, .)
    ),
    x_score = x_1 + x_2 + x_3
  )
```

produces the expected result, since it doesn't refer back to `df` with `(.)` when creating `x_score`.

For a more general solution for arbitrarily many `x_` variables, I'd suggest `pivot_longer()`:

```
df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("x_")) |>
  mutate(
    x_miscount = sum(is.na(value)), 
    x_mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
    value = if_else(is.na(value) & x_miscount == 1, x_mean, value),
    x_score = sum(value),
    .by = id
  ) |> 
  pivot_wider() |> 
  select(!id) |> 
  relocate(x_1:x_3, .before = y_1)
```

Comment: I just hadn't thought of that, but you're absolutely right. 

Unfortunately, this is my first question and I don't have enough reputation to give you an upvote. **Thank you very much**.